# Adding custom fields to license check requests using Android LVL

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am using the LVL provided by Google to use the Android Market Licensing Service.

I want to cache the server response but I do not want to use an obfuscated `SharedPreference` file to store license data because I have concerns about storing the key securely. I just want to be able to dump the encrypted response to a `SharedPreference` file so that nobody else can tamper with it. It is OK if they can view it.

Now, there are obviously some parameters that are not part of the server response. For example, the number of retries the app has made. I want to store that along with the response.

Is there any way I can append some custom data to the license request so that the server echos it back with the response after encrypting it? (Maybe as an extra field).

Will the server append any custom data I might send along with the request?

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that if you're using the default Server Managed Policy, you will be required to obfuscate because the second parameter of ServerManagedPolicy is obfuscation. This file is then dumped to the shared_prefs directory of your app.

To be honest I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, if a user has access to a file, they can certainly tamper with it. If you have concerns about storing the key securely, why would you want to disable obfuscation?

Also, I highly doubt you could obtain "custom" responses from the licensing server, someone please correct me if I'm wrong.